# Why does this javascript onclick load code run without me explicitly telling it to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, window

I have some javascript that changes a # hash URL and loads some HTML into an element using AJAX.

```
// Manually trigger a hashchange to start the app.
$(window).trigger('hashchange');


function makeContentView() {
  document.location.hash = "content";
  return false; // we don't want event propagation - just AJAX call
}


$(function () {

  $(window).on('hashchange', function () {
    // On every hash change the render function is called with the new hash.
    // This is how the navigation of our app happens.
    render(window.location.hash);
  });

  function render(url) {
    // This function decides what type of page to show 
    // depending on the current url hash value.

    switch (url) {
      case "#home":
        $("#AJAX_Parent").load("body/index_body.html #AJAX_Child");
        break;
      case "#grid":
        $("#AJAX_Parent").load("body/grid_body.html #AJAX_Child", function () {

            var contents = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnailImage");

              for (i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {

                // THIS FUNCTION GETS CALLED WITHOUT ME CLICKING
                contents.item(i).onclick = makeContentView();
              }

          }); // makeContentView IS ALWAYS BEING CALLED IMMEDIATELY
    ... // More switch options
```

^ Note that in the above example, the "contents.item(i).onclick = makeContentView();" assigns the makeContentView function to the onclick handler of my page's thumbnail images, but this makeContentView function is triggered unconditionally.

I only want makeContentView to be called when I click on one of the 6 thumbnail images with class=thumbnailImage

Comment: It's getting called because you are calling it. `makeContentView()` calls the function. What more is there to say other than... "duh"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Oh my god. It's calling the function and then returning the result. -_-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
makeContentView();
```

That is a function invocation.  Leave off the () to assign the function reference.

Answer (score 1):

because you are invoking it, simply make it

```
contents.item(i).onclick = makeContentView; //remove the parenthesis from the end
```

Answer (score 1):

By putting `()` right after function name you call it immediately. Remove them to assign a function as onclick handler (you're assigning its result now).

Answer (score 1):

You want `contents.item(i).onclick = makeContentView` *without* the parentheses. The reason is that Javascript basically runs any function it finds with `()` at the end of it *as soon as it reads it*.

You don't *want* Javascript to run this function as soon as it reads it. Instead, you want to just tell Javascript about the function -- that is, you just want to *reference* the function, rather than *call* it.